# Hardware Enable/Disable in vb6

Tags: vba, vb6, vbscript

I need to find a way to enable and disable a cd driver just like you can do in Device Manager by right clicking on th item. I am looking at WMI. If anyone has any ideas please let me know. Thanks

Comment: I know this is old question and you already accept an aswer, but take a look anyway at this: http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/5858c83b-e568-4b87-92ff-6edc45793f65

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use DevCon in Windows to disable a specific device.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff544746(v=vs.85).aspx#ddk_example_31_disable_devices_by_device_instance_id_tools

Comment: thanks for that, I've never heard of this program. But then again, I don't do device driver development. Does a developer have permission to distribute this program? And I take it that the user process initiating this would have to, at the least, have admin permissions?

Comment: I can't find a direct license agreement from the website. It is part of the WDK, which is freely distributed. I think its gonna be enough. Yeap, the user would need administrator permissions for it (or answer a UAC prompt).

Answer (score 0):

Use the sc command. It does drivers and services. In listing it defaults to services only but can be told to do drivers. It loads/unloads a driver or sets how it loads.

```
sc query type= driver
```

to unload

```
sc stop cdrom
```

to set from starting

```
sc config cdrom start= disabled
```

to set to start as a boot driver

```
sc config cdrom start= boot
```